# How to provide count of days between two dates in SAS

Tags: date, sas, countdown

I have several periods of time each year where day zero is a particular day. I need to create a list of all dates going forward and backward between the start and end of the period with their associated day number.

Here is an example:
Start Date (08APR2016)
Day Zero (01May2016)
End Date (04Aug2016)

The list would look like this:

```
Day  Date
-37  08APR2016
-36  09APR2016
 .
 .
 0   01MAY2016
 1   02May2016
 .
 .
 94  04AUG2016
```

I'm not sure how to write the SAS code necessary to do this and any assistance would be appreciated.

I'm currently doing it by creating an id variable with *N* which counts from start date to end date. For each list I then add the correct number to make the date I want zero. So in the example above for example I would do *N* -38 for the first one and then count up from there.

However, it gets messy when doing it for multiple lists and I was hoping there was a quick way to make a certain day zero and then count backwards to the first day and forwards to the last day.

Comment: To meet SO rules you need to post what you've tried. SAS dates are integers (google it) so you can increment/count them as regular numbers and the logic will be correct. If you have start and end, ignore the zero day and loop from start to end, and only use zero day to calculate the difference. Because the dates are integers to calculate difference you can subtract dates directly.

Answer (score 0):

what you're asking is pretty straight forward.  You should try some stuff and see what works and what doesn't.

```
data want;
retain day date;
keep day date;
format date date9.;

startDate = '08APR2016'd;
endDate   = '04AUG2016'd;
zeroDate  = '01MAY2016'd;

do i = startDate to endDate;
   day = i - zeroDate;
   date = i;
   output;
end;
run;
```